# Evaluating a statement involving logical implication

Tags: logic

An exercise question asks the following:

> Evaluate the following logical statement:
>
> $\neg[$Pigs don't want to fly$] \Rightarrow [$Pigs will fly$]$

I believe I can rewrite the statement as follows:

$\neg[$Pigs don't want to fly$] \Rightarrow [$Pigs will fly$] \Longleftrightarrow [$Pigs don't want to fly$] \lor [$Pigs will fly$] \Longleftrightarrow \neg[$Pigs want to fly$] \lor [$Pigs will fly$]$.

This doesn't help me answer the question, though. At the end of the day, I can assume $[$Pigs want to fly$] \in \mathbb{B}$ and $[$Pigs will fly$] \in \mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B} = \left\{ \textrm{T}, \textrm{F} \right\}$ but if I don't know either of the values I surely have no way of giving an answer of true or false for this question, right?

Is the whole statement just ambiguous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exercise has now been reviewed. The solution to this question required students to arbitrarily assign truth values to the propositions involved in the questions, however this requirement was not included or mentioned anywhere in the original exercise question.